# Python and the self parameter

Tags: python

I'm having some issues with the self parameter, and some seemingly inconsistent behavior in Python is annoying me, so I figure I better ask some people in the know. I have a class, `Foo`. This class will have a bunch of methods, `m1`, through `mN`. For some of these, I will use a standard definition, like in the case of `m1` below. But for others, it's more convinient to just assign the method name directly, like I've done with `m2` and `m3`.

```
import os

def myfun(x, y):
    return x + y

class Foo():
    def m1(self, y, z):
        return y + z + 42

    m2 = os.access
    m3 = myfun

f = Foo()
print f.m1(1, 2)
print f.m2("/", os.R_OK)
print f.m3(3, 4)
```

Now, I know that `os.access` does not take a `self` parameter (seemingly). And it still has no issues with this type of assignment. However, I cannot do the same for my own modules (imagine `myfun` defined off in `mymodule.myfun`). Running the above code yields the following output:

```
3
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 16, in <module>
    print f.m3(3, 4)
TypeError: myfun() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The problem is that, due to the framework I work in, I cannot avoid having a class `Foo` at least. But I'd like to avoid having my `mymodule` stuff in a dummy class. In order to do this, I need to do something ala

```
def m3(self,a1, a2):
    return mymodule.myfun(a1,a2)
```

Which is hugely redundant when you have like 20 of them. So, the question is, either how do I do this in a totally different and obviously much smarter way, or how can I make my own modules behave like the built-in ones, so it does not complain about receiving 1 argument too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to add that the behaviour is not inconsistent as already Luke hinted.

Just try the following

```
print Foo.__dict__
    {'__doc__': None,
     '__module__': '__main__',
     'm1': <function m1 at 0x02861630>,
     'm2': <built-in function access>,
     'm3': <function myfun at 0x028616F0>}
```

Here you can see that Python can't distinguish between m1 and m2.
That's why both are evaluated to a bound-method.

A bound method is something like a method with an additional first argument pointing to an object: `self.m(1, 2) -> m(self, 1, 2)`

This binding behaviour is only implemented for User-defined methods. That explains why `self.m2("/", os.R_OK)` is not evaluated to `m2(self, "/", os.R_OK)`.

One last demo:

```
print Foo.m1
    <unbound method Foo.m1>
print Foo.m2
    <built-in function access>
print f.m1
    <bound method Foo.m1 of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x02324418>>
print f.m2
    <built-in function access>
```

Further information about the different function types can be found here:

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

And as mentioned before this binding mechanism can also be prevented by using a *staticmethod descriptor*:

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Answer (score 4):

`os.access()` is a built-in function, in the sense that it's part of an extension module written in C. When the class is defined, Python doesn't recognize `m2` as a method because it's the wrong type — methods are Python functions, not C functions. `m3`, however, is a Python function, so it's recognized as a method and handled as such.

In other words, it's `m2` that's exceptional here, not `m3`.

One simple way to do what you want would be to make `m3` a static method:

```
m3 = staticmethod(myfun)
```

Now the interpreter knows never to try and pass `myfun()` a `self` parameter when it's called as the `m3` method of a Foo object.

Comment: your general point makes sense, but I don't see how its relevant whether the module is written in C, Python, or Befunge

Comment: The point is that it's run as *native code*, dynamically linked into the interpreter. You're right, though, it could be in any compiled language.

Comment: The `staticmethod` makes things work fine. But things should not work differently, when built-in or native code, or whatever IMO. So I guess I'll settle for working code, and the understanding will have to come at some other time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for staticmethod().  See docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

```
m2 = staticmethod(os.access)
m3 = staticmethod(myfun)
```

As to why m2 worked in your example and m3 didn't, that's not clear to me.  Printing f.m2 and f.m3 in your original example reveals that f.m2 is a direct reference to built-in function os.access, while f.m3 is a bound method (bound to the instance f).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) function in this case. When writing static class methods, you can use it as a decorator:

```
class A:
   def printValue(self,value):
       print value

   @staticmethod
   def staticPrintValue(value):
       print value

>>> A.printValue(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    A.printValue(5)
TypeError: unbound method printValue() must be called with A instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

>>> A.staticPrintValue(5)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to manually apply the static method decorator:

```
class Foo(object):
    m3 = staticmethod(mymodule.myfun)
```